# Trying to create simple java menu, but its not working

Tags: java

This is the code. I gives me an error where the switch is. Please help. Maybe a link to a site where i can learn this.

```
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int swValue;

    System.out.println("***************************************Menu***************************************");
    System.out.println("Spauskite 1 jei norite atspauzdinti programje sukurtu objektu sarasus");
    System.out.println("Spauskite 2 jei norite sukurti naujus objektus, ju duomenis ivedant is klavieturos");
    System.out.println("Spauskite 3 jei norite iskviesti objektu metodus");

    switch (swValue) {
    case 1: System.out.println("1 Selected");
        break;
    case 2: System.out.println("2 Selected");
        break;
    case 3: System.out.println("3 Selected");
        break;
    default: System.out.println("Invalis selection");
    break;
    }
```

Comment: not much of a menu if the user can't choose an option first (aka: ask the user and initialize `swValue` with whatever the user tells you)

Answer (score 2):

It is a compiler error to use a local variable before it's initialized, and you didn't initialize it.

It looks like you will want to read the user input and initialize `swValue` before the `switch` statement.

Comment: Can u give me an example how to fix this?

Comment: There are many ways, but two off the top of my head: 1) Initialize it to some value with `int swValue = 0;`, but that's not very useful here. 2) Use a `Scanner` to read the user input and assign the value to `swValue`.

Comment: A few more ways: 3) Use a `BufferedReader` to read user input, converting it to an `int` with `Integer.parseInt`.  4) Read a command-line parameter in the `args` parameter of `main` and convert it to an `int`.  5) Use `JOptionPane` to ask the user via a dialog box and convert the answer to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating some kind of input reading;

```
    //print out menu options

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {
       swValue = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
       ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    //switching code
```

Answer (score 0):

`swValue` isn't initialised i.e. there is not value assigned to it. So, how can you compare it to anything ?

If you want to get a value from the user, you can do either :

1. Accept `swValue` as a `parameter` :

   void main(String[] args, int swValue)
2. Use the `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` classes to get input at run-time.